Holt's Theorem on doubly transitive groups with $2$-central involutions fixing only one letter
In D. F. Holt, Transitive permutation groups in which an involution central in a Sylow 2-subgroup fixes a unique point, Proc. London Math. Soc. 37 (1978), 165–192, Derek Holt classifies finite doubly transitive permutation groups in which some $2$-central involution fixes precisely one letter.
My question: is there also such a result in the case of finite doubly transitive permutation groups in which some $p$-central element of order $p$ fixes precisely one letter, with $p$ an odd prime [without using the classification of finite simple groups] ?
(So in that case, if $G$ is the group acting on the finite set $X$ with $\vert X \vert = m + 1$, $p$ would divide $m$ and there would exist some element $\theta$ in a one-point stabilizer $G_x$, $x \in X$, which is central in a Sylow $p$-subgroup in $G_x$, while only fixing $x$ itself.)

That was a long time ago, but IIRC then all transitive groups with a 2-central involution fixing a unique point are classified, not just doubly transitive groups. The proof is very technical and predated the classification of finite simple groups. But Daniel Gorenstein told me later that they they had managed to avoid citing this result in the final proof of CFSG.

This may be hard to do without CFSG. For example, if $G$ acts doubly transitively on one of its conjugacy classes of elements of order $p$, this is comparable in difficulty (and a special case of) Glauberman's $Z^{\ast}$-theorem for odd $p$. Fischer and Aschbacher proved some results of this type. ( To be precise, this is a special case of odd $Z^{\ast}$ in the case that not all conjugates of the element of order $p$ commute).
