Doubly transitive groups with inequivalent doubly transitive group actions
Using the classification of finite simple groups, one can classify finite doubly transitive groups and their actions. Some of them though, such as $\mathsf{PSL}(d,q)$ ($d \geq 2$ and $q$ a prime power), have more than one doubly transitive permutation representation of the same degree (in this particular case, there are two inequivalent actions with the same permutation character).
My question: what are the finite doubly transitive groups which have inequivalent doubly transitive permutation representations of the same degree and with the same permutation character ?

This user doesn't care about the answers of his similar questions, see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484246, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483377, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468406.

@PeterMueller: I do not understand your remark. In none of these examples a complete list is mentioned with such representations -- only examples are given ?

For instance regarding https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484246: You ask "[...] do the other examples [...] also have this property, and if so, how is this proved ?". The answer given there is complete in the sense that it shows that the answer to your question is negative. Beyond that, it gives more information than was actually asked for.

@PeterMueller: yes indeed, but it still does not answer my current question, if I'm not mistaken.
